# variables affect the trajectory in a stochastic way

Tags: orbital-mechanics, trajectory, mathematics

What are the different variables affecting the trajectory of a rocket in a [stochastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic) way for getting potential three-sigma trajectory?

Comment: I'm scared of the word "stochastic" because it reminds me of thermodynamics and other challenging concepts. Also, is it only things which meet the textbook definition of stochastic that contribute to three-sigma? What about variables that have some correlation with each other, and are therefore not necessarily independently random?

Comment: You should specify which part of a flight you're talking about. During launch, during correction maneuvers, deep space missions?

Comment: @asdfex - looking at all phases actually. But this is for getting from earth to LEO. so no deep space stuff. I am trying to understand what are the variables affecting where spent stages impact the surface of the earth.

Comment: @uhoh - fair point. Indeed there are correlations and probably even stuff that is deterministic. But I am in a simpler pursuit here. Trying to find out all the variables I should keep in mind if I want to understand where spent stages will fall.

Comment: This Apollo/Soyuz Test Project trajectory dispersion analysis may provide some answer to your question.
https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19760004113.pdf

Comment: For ascent part, instead of just stochastic, you should look at control theory; the rocket is influenced by several random factors like wind, but they are all actively compensated for by the guidance systems. For drop of the stages, you'll have just the ballistic trajectory of an irregular body. Aerodynamic forces spinning it and as result changing the aerodynamic profile, changing the aerodynamic forces again.

Comment: @user56821 awesome reference. Thank you!

Comment: @SF. sure. will keep that in mind.